# Click a button defined as a DIV with a SVG linked to a path with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, html, web-scraping

I am making an Excel sheet that takes pictures from a webshop and places them on Pinterest.

When I try to submit the image URL I can't find the element to perform a click event.

Full HTML code from Pinterest.

```
<div data-test-id="website-link-submit-button" class="_50 _5a _6e _h _z7 _4q _j" style="height: 100%;">
    <svg class="_u0 _3a _u1 _45" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Verzenden" role="img">
      <title>Verzenden</title>
      <path d="M6.72 24c.57 0 1.14-.22 1.57-.66L19.5 12 8.29.66c-.86-.88-2.27-.88-3.14 0-.87.88-.87 2.3 0 3.18L13.21 12l-8.06 8.16c-.87.88-.87 2.3 0 3.18.43.44 1 .66 1.57.66"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")     
For Each HTMLbutton In HTMLButtons
  Debug.Print HTMLbutton.className
Next HTMLbutton
```

and

```
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")     
For Each HTMLbutton In HTMLButtons
  Debug.Print HTMLbutton.className
Next HTMLbutton
```

but neither of them has given me a useful index that can be combined with a .click event.

=========================================================================
EDIT

There are three steps to get to the code that is mentioned above.

In the picture underneath you will see the three steps.
number three is the button i need to click which when inspected shows the mentioned code.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the div is clickable but you can select the div with css attribute = value selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[data-test-id='website-link-submit-button']")
```

You can get the svg with

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden]")
```

You can get the path with

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden] > title + path")
```

You can click by adding

```
.click
```

or

```
.FireEvent "onclick"
```

to the end of the above e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden]").click 
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden] > title + path").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have edited my question. in this picture, you will find a couple of steps. if I click number one a text field (number 2) and the button (number3) appears. My VBA fills in this text field but i need to find a way to click button (number 3)

Comment: What is the html for button in step 3?

Comment: This is everything assigned to the arrow (number 3)

<div data-test-id="website-link-submit-button" class="_50 _5a _6e _h _z7 _4q _j" style="height: 100%;">

<svg class="_u0 _3a _u1 _45" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Verzenden" role="img">

<title>Verzenden</title>

<path d="M6.72 24c.57 0 1.14-.22 1.57-.66L19.5 12 8.29.66c-.86-.88-2.27-.88-3.14 0-.87.88-.87 2.3 0 3.18L13.21 12l-8.06 8.16c-.87.88-.87 2.3 0 3.18.43.44 1 .66 1.57.66"></path>

</svg>

</div>

Comment: my code above covers all those elements.  Did you add .click to the end? Or .FireEvent "onclick" ?

Comment: so please walk me through it. 
i place one of those codes you recommended and do something like
"set button = ie.document.queryselector("[data-test-id="website-link-submit-button"]")
and then
button.click
?

Comment: you would add either .click or .FireEvent "onclick" to the end of the above e.g.  ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden]").click or ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label=Verzenden] > title + path").FireEvent "onclick"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185924/discussion-between-jordi-beyen-and-qharr).